# Making unique Composite index in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am developing a access database front-end, where the database resides in SharePoint list. There is a `Attendance Table` with `AttDate` and `StaffID` columns apart from other columns.

Want to achieve: Only one record is added per staff for a day. i.e. only One Attendance is recorded in a day. When user tries to enter attendance of same staff again on same day, he should get error.

When the back-end was in Access file, I had created an index with 2 columns, and made the index "allow unique values only". The screen looks like this.
[image: Screenshot of Indexes]

Now when, I am moving my back-end to SharePoint, I was expecting same functionality. But, moving Tables to SharePoint using Access 2013 wizard did not create the index. Hence I thought creating it manually will solve the problem. So, I created an index with 2 columns, See screenshot below.
[image: SharePoint Index Shcreenshot]

> When I entered data, it still allows multiple values , see Screenshot
>   below

[image: Attendance Table]

> Please help, as to what can be the solution to this problem. I am
>   allowed to change existing table structure, if the solution so
>   demands. Any workaround will also be helpful.

Comment: Similar Q for Sharepoint 2010 at - http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/22770
Here, the solution said is `ItemUpdating event receiver`, but how to do this is not explained, if HOW is explained, may be this will solve the problem at hand.

Comment: Another good article about 2010 is https://salnikan.wordpress.com/2011/07/26/. 

But the solution will not work if data is added through other than SharePoint UI. 

In my case, the data will be entered through access front-end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint indexing is more about making it faster to retrieve and search for items in SharePoint. It has nothing to do with unique constraints.

You're going to have to add something to your SharePoint instance that will perform this check for you.

You haven't mentioned whether you're using SharePoint on-line or on-premise. You do say that you're using the Access front-end. This typically means you'll need to use an event receiver which will involve C# (or VB.NET) programming.

- Workflows wouldn't prevent the duplicate row from being saved
- JavaScript would help if using SharePoint UI, but won't prevent services

You do mention that you're using an Access front-end. Maybe you can add some business logic in your Access file?

Hope this helps

Comment: I have purchased Office 365. Hence SharePoint is online version.

Can you please guide to link where I can get info as to how to add event receiver which will involve C# (or VB.NET) programming.